# Overlap objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Hey guys!

I've been working on this for a long time. How would I overlap the "ACM" over the belly of this penguin? I tried to move the "A", "C", and "M" layers over the belly, use Object >> Arrange >> Bring to front, but nothing changed.

Comment: Hi PooofyOwl, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Are you sure the ACM have a solid background color and that it's not transparent? If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Another thing to check: are the letters multiplied on top of the penguin? Check in the transparency window. If they  are, and the fill is white, then it will behave as if it would be transparent.

Comment: There's no visible reason. So... it must be due to file structure. Since all we can see is a screen shot.. one *guess* is as good as any other *guess*. This can't be answered definitively based upon what you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is not the problem that @AmelieM mentions (no fill on the letters)...

Sometimes this happens to me and it has always a different reason: groups I left behind, objects I dragged from different artboards, convoluted layer structures, etc. Instead of spending much time trying to find the reason, I suggest you use my "fine-be-that-way" technique.

- Sigh deeply
- Select the 3 letters together using the Selection Tool (V) a.k.a. "black arrow".
- Cut the 3 letters to the clipboard (Ctrl-X on PC or Command-X on Mac)
- Select the penguin with the black arrow.
- Paste the 3 letters you just copied (Ctrl-V or Command-V). This will paste the 3 letters on a layer on top of the penguin's.
- Move the letters into position.
- Carry on and forget your troubles.

If you want us to forensic your file, though, and find The Reason, please post it along with your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the letters have no fill, you have just the strokes. Anyway, just arranging layers will not work here as you probably want, for example for letter M, a part of it lay below the shape of the hand, and the other part-above it, so you might want to split your shapes, for example the hand, using Pathfinder under Effects.

Comment: Hi Amelie, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!